# How to pass nextPage variable value from child to parent's router-link?

Tags: vue.js

Trying to set the value of `<router-link :to="{nextPage}">`from a child component to make the router-link dynamic.

Some of the research I did talked about adding a prop, but I'm not too sure where that should go. In `<router-view :next-page="">`?

When I do this I have two problems:

Problem 1: solved

Problem 2: an error message "The data property "nextPage" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead."

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view :nextPage="['/']"></router-view>

    <router-link class="prev-slide" :to="'/'">
      Restart
    </router-link>
    <router-link class="next-slide" :to="nextPage">
      Next
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      nextPage: "/page2"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Welcome.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Welcome",
  props: ['nextPage'],
  data() {
    return {
      nextPage: "/page2"
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: To fix problem 2, change your data variable in welcome.vue from nextPage to something else or simply use the prop itself.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use computed. if you don't know anything about this; let me give you an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  props: {
    current: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    }
  },
  computed: {
    next() {
      return this.current  + 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
{{current}}
|
{{next}}
</div>
```

if you need get current page from route:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    current() {
      return this.$route.params.page
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{current}}</div>
```